# Are there any other uses for unique items other than transmuting them?

Tags: torchlight-2

Ever since I discovered that you can transmute multiple unique items into a single unique item, I've been hoarding uniques.  However, I've since come to the conclusion that transmuting uniques is a waste of time because my transmutes always result in an item that 1) isn't better than anything I already have or 2) can't be used by my character class.  Therefore, I've decided that selling my lot of uniques is the best bet.  Before I do that, though, I am wondering if they possibly serve any other purpose.

Comment: As long as we're listing ALL the uses for unique items, here's a tongue-in-cheek response: You can equip them.

Comment: My tongue is certainly in my cheek with that one.

Comment: As has been explained below, transmuting doesn't give you a better item, just a different one.  In most cases it is more cost effective to simply sell the item.  I tend to give away my hoard to my friends but that's just me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer to this is : No, there is no real reason to hoard uniques.

The explaination being that, transmuting uniques usually just grants you a unique around the same level as the uniques you transmuted. Considering the fact that by the time you collect enough uniques of a certain level for transmuting your character would have levelled past it, and you will always end up with a unique that is slightly behind your level. There may be exceptions to this and you might get a useful item every now and then.(I lucked out once or twice and I have done this over a hundred times!!) But the thing still remains that hoarding in TL2 is discouraged unlike its predecessor. Gem combining and other mechanics that promote hoarding have been removed.

I usually just transmute them if I have enough in my inventory, just to see if I have any luck, but long term hoarding and item farming based around transmuting is just not worth the time , effort, or inventory/stash slots.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your play style, you may also want to keep them in the shared stash, either for future characters, especially of different classes for those restricted items, or to give to other players in multiplayer.

Comment: That applies to all items.